# Does $C+$ core $D \subset$ core $(C+D)$?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $C$ and $D$ be convex subsets of a real vector space $\mathcal{X}$. We want to show that $C+$ core $D \subset$ core $(C+D)$, where core $C$ is defined as
$$
    \operatorname{core}(C) := \big\{ x \in C \, \big| \, \forall \, u \in \mathcal{X}, \, \exists \, \lambda \in (0, \infty), \, x + \alpha \lambda u \in C, \text{ for any } \alpha \in [0, 1]\big\}.
$$

**My attempt:**
For any $x_1 = y_1 + z_1 \in C + \operatorname{core}(D)$ with $y_1 \in C$ and $z_1 \in \operatorname{core}(D)$, consider $x_2 = y_2 + z_2 \in C + D$ with $y_2 \in C$ and $z_2 \in D$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    \exists \, \lambda_0 \in \, ] 0, + \infty [, \qquad [z_1, z_1 + \lambda_0 z_2] = \{ z_1 + \alpha \lambda_0 z_2 : \alpha \in [0, 1]\} \subseteq D.
\end{equation*}
Then for any $\alpha \in [0, 1]$, we want to find $\lambda_0^{\prime}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    y_1 + z_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} (y_2 + z_2) = (y_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} y_2) + (z_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} z_2),
\end{equation*}
with $y_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} y_2 \in C$ and $z_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} z_2 \in D$. However, the biggest problem in this method is that we cannot promise that $y_1 + \alpha \lambda_0^{\prime} y_2$ is always in $C$ as the coefficient of $y_1$ is $1$ instead of something between 0 and 1.

Is there an alternative method to prove? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You got the definition of $core(C+D)$ wrong.

Comment: @daw Yes. I checked my note, I made a mistake. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c\in C$, $d\in core \ D$, $u \in X$. We have to check that there is $\lambda>0$ such that $c+d + \alpha \lambda u\in C+D$ for all $\alpha\in [0,1]$.

Since $d\in core \ D$ there is $\lambda>0$ such that $d + \alpha \lambda u\in D$. But then $c+(d + \alpha \lambda u) \in C+D$, and $c+d\in core(C+D)$.